# User HDFS quota management in Cosmos

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

As far as we know, each Cosmos user in the FIWARE Lab (cosmos.lab.fiware.org) has a maximum of 5GB available in HDFS.
Nevertheless we are getting a `DSQuotaExceededException` when running our map-reduce Hadoop jobs in spite of the data generated by the job doesn't exceed the 5GB quota.

If we monitor the HDFS usage during the execution of the map-reduce job, we get the following output:

```
Command: "while true; do date; hadoop fs -count -q . ; sleep 20; done"
Format:
DATE
QUOTA  REMAINING_QUOTA SPACE_QUOTA    REMAINING_SPACE_QUOTA DIR_COUNT  FILE_COUNT CONTENT_SIZE   FILE_NAME

jue jul 28 18:50:12 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197734302           19           46         1389627219 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:50:34 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           26          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:50:57 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           26          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:51:20 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           26          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:51:44 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           26          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:52:07 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           26          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:52:28 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1198032544           22           35         1389528792 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:52:50 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197738517           19           39         1389625814 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:53:11 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           27          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:53:35 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           27          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:53:59 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           27          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:54:22 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           27          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:54:46 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           27          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:55:09 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2477420902           17           28          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:55:31 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197738514           19           39         1389625815 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:55:55 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197738514           20           48         1389625815 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:56:17 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747506           16           28          895957138 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:56:40 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747506           16           28          895957138 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:57:04 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747506           16           28          895957138 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:57:28 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747506           16           28          895957138 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:57:51 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747506           16           28          895957138 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:58:13 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1198032556           16           37         1389528788 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:58:34 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197738742           19           40         1389625760 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:58:56 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           29          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:59:20 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           29          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 18:59:43 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           29          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:00:07 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           29          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:00:31 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      2678747494           16           29          895957142 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:00:54 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1076586601           22           38         1228684181 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:01:18 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197724648           19           41         1389630437 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:01:41 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197724648           19           41         1389630437 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:02:05 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197724648           19           41         1389630437 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:02:29 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197724648           19           41         1389630437 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:02:53 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120      1197724648           19           41         1389630437 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:03:14 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       364004107           19           46         1667537284 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:03:36 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       197959591           20           48         1722885456 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:03:57 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       201060881           18           44         1722549413 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:04:19 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       201060881           18           44         1722549413 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:04:40 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       201060881           18           44         1722549413 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:05:02 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       201060881           18           44         1722549413 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
jue jul 28 19:05:23 CEST 2016
        none             inf      5368709120       201060881           18           44         1722549413 hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/rbarriuso
```

After a while the execution finishes with this exception:

```
16/07/28 19:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201604111313_157784_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DSQuotaExceededException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DSQuotaExceededException: The DiskSpace quota of /user/rbarriuso is exceeded: quota=5368709120 diskspace consumed=5.0g
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2400(DFSClient.java:2846)
    at org.apache.ha...
```

As you can see at the end of the log above, the maximum HDFS usage corresponds to 1.722.549.413 bytes and 201.060.881 bytes of free quota (according to `hadoop fs -count -q`), which doesn't sum the 5GB of available user space.
Moreover, the taken space doesn't match the remaining free space.

How is the remaining quota space calculated?
Is there any way to avoid the `DSQuotaExceededException`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take into account the replication factor HDFS applies to all the data. By default, this is 3, thus your effective quota is 5GB/3. This quota can be increased by contacting the admin (me :)) via email.